# How could I send file to my other buddy on my chat app?

Tags: android, iphone, sockets, google-app-engine, xmpp

I have a chat app, and I want to add the functionality to send files to my buddy, and my buddy also send me files too. How could I do this? Thanks! My buddy is in other city

Answer (score 2):

Try  this code for sending data to other user over xmpp and make sure that user must be your friend and online otherwise you will not able to send data.

```
private void sendData(File file) {


        Log.i("Sending1","sending1");

        try {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ChatActivity.this.getParent(),"", "Please wait.");
            OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(secondUserName+"/Smack");
            //  String name = "DemoImage";n
            Log.i("Sending2","sending2");

            transfer.sendFile(file, "Demo Image");

            while (!transfer.isDone()) {
                if (transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
                    if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                        progressDialog.cancel();
                    }
                    System.out.println("ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(transfer.getStatus());
                    System.out.println(transfer.getProgress());
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ChatActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            if(transfer.isDone()){
                if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                }
                if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error))
                {

                    Constant.showToast(ChatActivity.this.getParent(), "Error in sending file please retry.");
                }else{
// do what you want.
}


            }
            //transfer.sendFile(fi, "Demo Images");
            Log.i("Sending3","sending3");
            //  transfer.sendFile(new File(filePath), "You won't believe this!");  
            //transfer.sendFile(new File("shakespeare_complete_works.txt"), "You won't believe this!");
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Sending4","sending4");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```

And for file transfering config like that

```
 private void configFileTransfer() {

            ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
            ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
            ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());

            // Create the file transfer manager  
            manager = new FileTransferManager(XMPPSmackConnection.connection);  
            FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(XMPPSmackConnection.connection, true);
            fileTransferListener();

        }

private void connect() {
        if(XMPPSmackConnection.connection==null || !XMPPSmackConnection.connection.isConnected()){ 
            reConnect();
        }else{
            XMPPSmackConnection.getInstance();
            //request = new MessageEventManager(XMPPSmackConnection.connection);
            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            XMPPSmackConnection.connection.sendPacket(presence);
            setConnection(XMPPSmackConnection.getInstance().connection);
            mHandler= new Handler();
            configFileTransfer();
        }
    }
```

and call connect on oncreate of activity